# Find a monic polynomial

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

For each $f \in K[x]$, find a monic polynomial satisfied by $f$ with coefficients in $K[x^2]$, where $K$ is a field.

Comment: What can you do yourself? Can you think of a solution for example when $f(x)=x$?

Comment: I was thinking as follows: any polynomial $f$ can be decomposed into an $g+xh$ where $g$ and $h$ are polynomials with even power of $x$ then, $(f-g)^2 = (xh)^2 $

Comment: @RohitBhagwat What about $f(T^2)-f(X^2)$? ($f$ can be supposed monic.)

Comment: @user26857 Hmm, that will work as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try
$$
(T-f(x))(T-f(-x)).
$$
The coefficients of various powers of $T$ are in $K[x^2]$, iff they are even polynomials.